# Asymptotic complexity of function with two Input variables

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose I have a function with two input below.

$f(m,n) = \log {n^m} + 100n \log \log {m^5} + 150m + 4n^2 + 1000$.

Is it safe to say that $f(m,n)$ is $\mathcal{O}(m \log n)$, or is it $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ instead? I think the first one is more representative as it includes the variable $m$. But that may not be the case if $n$ is relatively very larger than $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not safe to say either.  The intuition: When $n$ is really large, $f(m,n)$ grows faster than $O(m \log n)$.  When $m$ is really large, $f(m,n)$ grows faster than $O(n^2)$.

Instead, what you can say is that $f(m,n)$ is $O(m \log n + n^2 + n \log \log m)$.  Why?

$$\begin{align*}
f(m,n) &= \log {n^m} + 100n \log \log {m^5} + 150m + 4n^2 + 1000\\
  &=m \log n + 100n\log \log m + 100n\log 5 + 150m + 4n^2 + 1000\\
  &=O(m \log n) + O(n \log \log m) + O(n) + O(m) + O(n^2) + O(1)\\
  &=O(m \log n) + O(n \log \log m) + O(n^2) + O(m \log n) + O(n^2) + O(1)\\
  &=O(m \log n + n \log \log m + n^2).
\end{align*}$$

If $n \log \log m = O(m \log n + n^2)$ (I'm not sure if this is true), then you could simplify this to $O(m \log n + n^2)$.

Comment: $O(n\log\log m)$ cannot be changed to $O(n^2)$. A lemma like the following is required. $n\log\log m < m \log n + n^2$ if either $n$ is larger enough or $m$ is large enough. This lemma is, in fact, not immediate to prove although it might be intuitively clear for experienced users.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, oh, good point!  I'm not sure either.  Edited.